# Repopulate to Select Option

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to repopulate data to select option but i only have one select data and other select are not work, i think their are dependent on "change" function. Please ...

first i create **state and region** drop down with json data, then set **change** method on this select and get **district** data and populate those data at **district select**, then set change method on **district select** and get data for **township** and populate at **township select**.

**onclick function** set on btn_save and populate all data to table.

Here were my problem come out. i want to edit my data and i set edit button on table then i want to populate table data to previous select. but it's only work in **state region select**,

This is my simple html code

```
     <div>
        <select name="state" id="state">
            <option value="">State And Region</option>
        </select>        
        <select name="district" id="district">
            <option value="">District</option>
        </select>
        <select name="township" id="township">
            <option value="">Township</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="desc" placeholder="Enter your keyword"> 
        <button id="btn_save">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="tbl_desc">
            <tr>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>District</th>
                <th>Township</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is my js code

```
fetch('/data/lp_state_region.json')
.then( response => {
    return response.json()
})
.then(json => {
    $('#state').append(json.map( sr => {
        return `<option value=${sr.sr_code}>${sr.sr_name}</option>` ;
    }));
});

$('#state').change( e => {
    let sr_code = e.target.value ;
    fetch('/data/lp_district.json')
    .then( res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then( json => {
        $('#district').html('');
        $('#district').html(`<option value=''>District</option>`);
        $('#district').append(json.map(d => {
            if(sr_code == d.sr_code){
                return `<option value=${d.d_code}>${d.d_name}</option>` ;
            }
        }));
    });
});

$('#district').change( e => {
    let d_code = e.target.value ;
    fetch('/data/lp_township.json')
    .then( res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then( json => {
        $('#township').html('');
        $('#township').html(`<option value=''>Township</option>`);
        $('#township').append( json.map( ts => {
            if(ts.d_code == d_code){
                return `<option value=${ts.ts_code}>${ts.ts_name}</option>` ;
            }
        }));
    });
});

$('#btn_save').click(() => {
    let tr = "<tr>" ;
    tr += `<td class="state">${$('#state').val()}</td>` ;
    tr += `<td class="district">${$('#district').val()}</td>` ;
    tr += `<td class="township">${$('#township').val()}</td>` ;
    tr += `<td class="desc">${$('#desc').val()}</td>` ;
    tr += "<td><button onclick='rePopulateSelect(this);'>Edit</button></td>" ;
    tr += "</tr>" ;
    $(".tbl_desc").append(tr);

    $('#state').val('').change();
    $('#district').val('').change();
    $('#township').val('').change();
    $('#desc').val('');
});

function rePopulateSelect(btn){
    let tr = $(btn).closest('tr');
    let state = tr.find('.state').html() ;
    let district = tr.find('.district').html();
    let township = tr.find('.township').html();
    let desc = tr.find('.desc').html();
    
    // i want to repopulate this data to select
    // i am stuck at here
    $('#state').val(state).change();
    $('#district').val(district).change();
    $('#township').val(township).change();
    $('#desc').val(desc);
}
```

Comment: first thing that I can see is that you are assigning an event to `#district` and then triggering `#township`, anyway... live working example would be nice, if you want someone to fix your problem, make some jsfiddle or something.

Comment: thanks for your replay, here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ho3s3in/ya5usd81/

Comment: i just create a git page to clarify my question, https://hoesein.github.io/select_error/

Comment: I still don't understand the problem then, based on fiddle.

Comment: check my github page, my main problem is data don't populate to select when i click on edit button, so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are using fetch without waiting for the promise to fulfill.

When you make your calls at the end of `rePopulateSelect`:

```js
    $('#state').val(state).change();
    $('#district').val(district).change();
    $('#township').val(township).change();
    $('#desc').val(desc);
}
```

you are making some async-calls in your change-handler.
To solve this, try to await in the change-handlers, e.g. in your state-change-handler:

```js
// create function for initing districts
async function InitDistricts(selectedState) {
    await fetch('https://hoesein.github.io/select_error/data/lp_district.json')
    .then( res => {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then( json => {
        $('#district').html('');
        $('#district').html(`<option value=''>District</option>`);
        $('#district').append(json.map(d => {
            if(selectedState == d.sr_code){
                return `<option value=${d.d_code}>${d.d_name}</option>` ;
            }
        }));
    });
}

// attach as eventhandler
$('#state').change((e) => InitDistricts(e.target.value));

async function InitTownships(selectedDistrict) {
...
}
```

also in your rePopulateSelect use the functions you created and use await only when it makes sense...

```js
async function rePopulateSelect(btn) {

....

    $('#state').val(state);
    await InitDistricts(state);
    
    $('#district').val(district);
    await InitTownships(district);
    
    $('#township').val(township);
    $('#desc').val(desc);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advise, to clarify my question please check my git page, https://hoesein.github.io/select_error/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems that the problem is pretty obvious. You are changing the value of for example `#district`, that makes your `#district` select option to be set as `selected`. But as ajax is an async call, after that you are rewriting the code of the options so it doesn't contain any `selected` option.

You should append your selects in you ajax code with:

```
if(value = this_select_value) <option selected value="..."/>
else <option value="..."/>
```

And as `this_select_value` you should use some other select attribute than `value` (`val()`), as it's being rewritten when you clear the options with `html()`. Some virtual one, like `attr('last_val',val)`;

(not a valid code, just to show the idea, could fix your code, but I can't edit it on github)